# How to conditionally set labels for a mat-tab Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, mat-tab

I wanted to reduce the code of my component, two mat-tabs have exactly the same structural content but have different data and different labels. I want to set labels for them based on a condition that I will check. I tried doing this;

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let data of datas;let i=index;"label={{i==0 ? 'First' : {{'Tab '+ (i+1)}} }}">
```

but I cannot nest string interpolation. Writing the condition without the outer {{ results in the whole string i==0 ? Tab 2 getting printed. Any ideas on what I could do here?

Comment: Why don't you create a function or a getter in your TS code?

Comment: You don't actually need the second pair of curly braces. Try this `{{i==0 ? 'First' : 'Tab '+ (i+1) }}`.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev I could create a function , but the number of tabs could be upwards of 20 in some cases, wanted to find a native angular solution

Comment: The function can accept an argument. You don't need to declare N functions for N indexes.